# Finding the correct keyring tag

Tags: discussion

I've [created](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/676/how-to-change-or-remove-keyrings-on-elementary-os) the tag keyring on one question, but I'm wondering, does elementary use gnome's keyring system or something else?

I want to know what the tag should be exactly, so as to be more precise and not have a too broadly applicable tag.

Okay now that I know elementary uses Gnome's keyring system, vote on what the tag should be below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elementary does indeed use Gnome Keyring through the [LibSecret](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Libsecret) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[keyring](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyring)

The existing tag.

Answer (score 0):

[gnome-keyring](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnome-keyring)

(One con I can think of, is that elementary technically doesn't use Gnome and some users who aren't familiar with the wider Linux world might get confused a bit).

Answer (score 0):

```
ellie@elementary-freya:~$ ps $(pgrep keyring)
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1499 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

Yes, elementary uses Gnome-keyring. I can't find any trace of it in the UI: nothing about saved passwords and keys in the Security & Privacy settings.

Freedesktop has basically standardized Gnome-keyring as the keyring API, which makes the two pretty much synonymous in the Linux world now.